# Laravel validate if an ID has an instance of the relation

Tags: laravel, validation

This if kind of a finicky problem, and the title may be a bit confusing, so I'll try and explain as best as I can.

Basically, I am creating a Recipe application, where users can create lists and add recipes to them.

I want the lists to only be able to have one instance of each recipe, so for example, if I add Recipe 10 to List number 1, I don't want the user to be able to add Recipe 10 any more to List 1.

Right now I've only used validation for checking if the meal_id (the id for the recipe) already exists in the recipes table, but with this I am only able to add each recipe to one list.

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'meal_id' => 'required|unique:recipes,meal_id',
            'list_id' => 'required'
        ]);
```

My relations are simply that a Recipe hasOne RecipeList, and a RecipeList hasMany Recipes, but I'm fairly certain changing that up wont be the fix.

Recipe model

```
 class Recipe extends Model

    {
        use HasFactory;
    
        protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'meal_id',
            'list_id'
        ];
    
        public function lists()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(RecipeList::class);
        }
}
```

RecipeList model

```
class RecipeList extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function recipes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Recipe::class);
    }
}
```

Recipes table

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('recipes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('meal_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('list_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

However maybe I need to set up some form of pivot table?

Does anyone have any ideas on some smart way of achieving what I want through the validation, or any other ideas?

Comment: could you add your model/table structure to your question please?

Comment: @Ballard Added it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Rule` and create a custom validation to add your conditions.
Here I assume your condition is to add a unique restriction on both `list_id` and `meal_id`

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'list_id' => 'required',
        'meal_id' => [
            required,
            unique:recipes,meal_id,
            \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::unique('recipes')->where(function($query) use ($request){
                  $query->where('list_id', $request->list_id)
                      ->where('meal_id', $request->meal_id);
                }),
            ],
    ]);
```

Comment: @Oskar B, this is as mentioned in my answer the better way to achieve what you want

Comment: The problem persists. I am not sure exactly what this validation does, does it check if the list_id in the request has a match with the meal_id request?

Comment: Okay removing the regular unique validation seemed to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @OskarB Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Use `firstOrCreate()`. Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models

Example:

```
$recipeData = $request->validate([
    'name' => 'required',
    'meal_id' => 'required',
    'list_id' => 'required'
]);

$recipe = Recipe::firstOrCreate($recipeData);
```

This will use your 3 fields, `name`, `meal_id` & `list_id` and will either select one or create it if it doesn't exist already.

Alternatively you can do a query to check if it exists. If you want to return an error/message to the user explaining that the new one is a duplicate.

```
$existingRecipe = Recipe::where([
    'meal_id' => $recipeData['meal_id'], 
    'list_id' => $recipeData['list_id'], 
    'name' => $recipeData['name']])
->first();

if(!is_null($existingRecipe)) {
//return exists
}
```

Of course, using rules will be more efficient, depends on what you want your UI to express.

**See BABAK ASHRAFI's answer**

Comment: This is not the problem. The problem is that   ` 'meal_id' => 'required|unique:recipes,meal_id'` , checks unique for all recipes and not only for the ones in the list. He will either have to adjust the `Rule::unique()`method or make a custom Rule.

Comment: Correct, however, OP asked for other possible solutions and this is valid. I've updated my answer to remove the mis-copied validation rule there

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI I completely agree & understand, my post here was purely based on OP mentioning ```or any other ideas?```